# Treating array elements differently by the interfaces they implement

Tags: java

Let's assume there is an ArrayList that contains many different elements of type "Element". All of them will be drawn to the screen in an endless loop.

These "Element"s can implement 0..n interfaces like "Movable", "Selectable" and so on.

What I tried so far is iterating through all Elements and check for an interface like:

```
ArrayList<Element> allElements;
...

for (Element element : allElements) {
  if (element instanceof Movable) {
    ((Movable)element).move();
  }
  if (element instanceof Selectable) {
    ...
  }

  element.draw();
}
```

I'm not happy with that approach, though, because it violates the open/closed principle (and probably thousands of other principles too). Of course, I could re-design it so that each element responds itself according to the interfaces it implements:

```
for (Element element : allElements) {
  element.move(); // element checks itself if it can move, and if true moves
  ...
}
```

The drawback is that the Element class must provide signatures for each possible behavior, i.e. it must provide the methods of every interface and maybe override them in child classes. That's also not what I want because it bloats the Element class.

I also tried selecting Elements by interface like this:

```
getElementsByInterface(Movable, allElements) { ... }
```

(Movable is the interface, allElements the ArrayList)

But it doesn't compile. It seems Java doesn't know interfaces at run-time anymore.

Long story short (sorry for my possibly overly verbose post): 
What is the best design solution to let array elements react according to their abilities(/interfaces)?

Comment: "But it doesn't compile. It seems Java doesn't know interfaces at run-time anymore." These sentences contradict each other. What is the compiler error if it fails to compile? What is the exception if it fails at run-time? Perhaps you meant `getElementsByInterface(Movable.class, allElements)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded that more carefully but I forgot the exact error message. It sounds contradictory at first but it made sense to me: The code couldn't compile because the compiler detected that the interface will be no longer known at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing inherently wrong with this approach.

There are basically [two approaches](http://andymaleh.blogspot.com/2008/04/scalas-pattern-matching-visitor-pattern.html) to this scenario:

1. Use polymorphism and the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Due to (the interface aspect of) the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), this introduces the "drawback" described of each handler having to implement all actions.
2. Using local type-based switching (this is more common place in languages like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) with [ADTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) where this approach is [acceptable/common](http://blog.nirav.name/2009/04/how-scalas-pattern-matching-can-replace.html); the Java syntax is just a bit unwieldy in comparssion).

There is no violation of (polymorphic) [open/closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) here *because* interfaces are being used and the "action" is still left in the implementation (which still supports polymorphism and thus "open"); it is only the *selection* of action that is not.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that the right answer depends on how many times that or similar switch statements appears across your code base.

If it occurs in exactly one place, it's probably fine to leave it as is.

If it occurs in a heap of places, it's probably a good idea to refactor it out using the visitor pattern (or perhaps the Command and Composite patterns together, depending on the nature of change you're expecting).

Answer (score 1):

The [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) may be useful here.

Comment: This is the "drawback" mentioned; having to scale across Type implementations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You would just be replacing if blocks with Visitors.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use reflection for this??

I can suggest you one way.

Create a new interface say CanDoAction :

```
public interface CanDoAction{
    String getAction();
}
```

Then extend your interfaces from this and for the getAction method, return the name of the function to be called for corresponding interface. For Example, In the case of class implementing Movable, return "move" for getAction.

Then while looping :

```
for (Element element : allElements) {
    String actionName = ((CanDoAction)element).getAction();

    try {
        element.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(actionName, null)
                .invoke(element, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```